# Is there a way to install OpenCV binaries on Windows?

Tags: opencv

I need to use the traincascade and createsamples utilities.

I need to do this on many computers and do not want to have to build them myself as these computers do not have any development tools.

I have searched for instructions a lot, but they all say things like 'run the installer and install to Program Files' . Except that I don't see any installer. I have downloaded a 200MB exe OpenCV-2.4.0.exe, but on running it just extracts to some folder. That folder contains sources and cmake files, but I do not want to build myself. The library files are there, but no exe files (for traincascade and createsamples).

Answer (score 0):

build a 64 bit version and a 32 bit version on the lowest os you can find(xp, vista or 7), then build your own installer.

Comment: How do I 'build my own installer'? Is there no way I can directly get binaries? So many people are saying stuff like 'run the installer' so there must be an installer somewhere right?

Comment: google build your own installer for windows. if you can’t find it there might only be the unix installer